# Ngxs + Angular 17 = not compatible?

Tags: angular, ngxs

When I install NGXS in my Angular 17 project I get this error:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@">=12.0.0 <17.0.0" from @ngxs/store@3.8.1
```

I don't seem to find any specs on the NGXS website about what Angular versions I can and cannot use, but it seems to be an Angular version lower than 17? Am I doing something wrong because I can't seem to find any official info on this. Is there anyone that has made this work? The install succeeded when I used the *--force* parameter, but this is a workaround rather than a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngxs/store` supports v17 from `3.8.2` onwards. Please update to at least this version to use it with Angular v17 !

---

Old answer.

The v17 support is [pending PR](https://github.com/ngxs/store/pull/2079).

Until this is release, you can just force the install with `npm install --force` or add an `overrides` section in your package.json

Comment: Version `3.8.2` which support Angular 17 is now available: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngxs/store/v/3.8.2

For some reasons, the release on NPM took longer than usual... No idea why, AFAIK all previous major updates were within a few days.

Answer (score 2):

To register Ngxs in Angular 17, simply go to the `app.config.ts` and wrap it within the `importProvidersFrom()`, which you must import as well. Below is the complete file.

```
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule } from '@ngxs/devtools-plugin';
import { NgxsModule } from '@ngxs/store';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.development';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(
      NgxsModule.forRoot([/* Enter your state here */], {
        developmentMode: !environment.production,
      })
    ),
    importProvidersFrom(
      NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot({
        disabled: environment.production,
      })
    ),
  ],
};
```

#### NOTE:

The `environment` files have not been automatically included in Angular projects since Angular 15, but you can simply run `ng generate environments` to generate them. You'll also have to add the `production: false` into the file and write the inverse for the prod file, full file `environment.development.ts` below.

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add on, with SSR and standalone components (no app.module) being the preferred approach in angular 17, after npm i --force to get things running you must include importProvidersFrom in both app.config.ts and app.config.server.ts in the providers array.

```
    importProvidersFrom(
      NgxsModule.forRoot(
        [UserState]
    ),
    // devtools always last
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot()
    )
```

Comment: Yes, nice addition!